# how can display img from DB

Tags: php, database, image, pdo, echo

I have more than one image saved in DB that has the same VID, I need help to display all images depending on column VID when `VID == id`, this is my function it just displays the first image.

```php
<body>
    
<?php
    # database connection file
    require_once('conect.php');
    # fetching images
    $sql1  = "SELECT * FROM villa where id=94; ";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
    $stmt->execute();
    $images = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $num_of_row = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
        <div class="gallery">
            <h4>All Images</h4>
            <?php foreach ($images as $image) {
                echo $num_of_row;
                for ( $i=0;$stmt->rowCount() >$i;$i++)
                {
                    if ($image['id'] === $image['VID']){
                        echo $image['id'];
                        ?>
                        <img src="img/<?php echo ($image['imgV']);>">
                    <?php }
                }
            }?>
            
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

Comment: What is `$image['id']`? There is considerably more code here than is needed, and likely is inefficient for what you are trying to achieve... but unclear what that really is. Isn't `for ( $i=0;$stmt->rowCount() >$i;$i++)` the same as `foreach ($images as $image)`?

Comment: @`$image['id']` the **id** is Colum in my DB
i thought that it is same , but the foreach  it is not work ,i just try for with foreach.

Comment: I have more than one image saved in DB have same VID , I need help to display all images depending on column VID when VID == id ,this is my function it just display the first image. where VID and id are columns in DB

Comment: Please provide a sample value of the data stored in DB. Is that a base64 string of image, or just an image filename / URL ?

Comment: Please provide sample data. We wont be able to give an accurate answer otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
 <img src="img  . '<?php echo ($image['imgV']);?>' . ">
```

But you should't use php code in your template.
Php code base in. php files and templates in separate directory
Learn more about mvc.. )
Sorry for my English))))

Comment: my code is in  PHP file  , 'img/' represents the folder 
i try your code it isn't work .

Comment: if ($image['id'] === $image['VID']){
                    echo $image['id'];
                    
                 echo  '<img src="img . '$image['imgV']' . ">';
                <?php }

This works (on my pc )

Comment: I have more than one image saved in DB have same VID , I need help to display all images depending on column VID when VID == id ,this is my function it just display the first image. where VID and id are columns in DB

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I added `order by vid asc, id asc` at the end of your SQL. It will help to sort the dataset at first.

Second, I using a variable `$previousId` to compare the current row and previous row's VID.

```
<body>
<?php
    # database connection file
    require_once('conect.php');
    # fetching images
    $sql1  = "SELECT * FROM villa where id=94 order by VID asc, id asc;";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
    $stmt->execute();
    $images = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $num_of_row = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $previousId = null;
        ?>
            <div class="gallery">
                <h4>All Images</h4>
                <?php
                    foreach ($images as $image) {
                        echo $num_of_row;
                        if($previousId != $image['VID']){
                            echo $image['id'];
                            $previousId = $image['VID'];
                        }
                        echo '<img src="img/' . $image['imgV'] . '">' . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I answered way too off;

I would like to clarify first is $image['imgV'] already has the filename and the extension (.jpg, .png) etc. if not you need to add echo `'<img src="img/' . $image['imgV'] . '.jpg" />'` extension (.jpg) on your code.

*Also if you are using MVC, make sure you always declared your base_url so that all images, styles, and scripts you included in the VIEW won't confuse URL as a Directory.*